# How to open an android app as default using deeplink in Detox testing

Tags: android, automated-tests, detox

I am trying to open a particular page for my react native app using Detox. While passing the deeplink in the below methods, in *Android* it prompts to select either my app or *Chrome*. Is there a way to make my app as default for these links in Detox?
I have tried both of these

`await device.openURL({url: '{{URL}}'`

and also

```
await device.launchApp({
  url: '{{URL}}',
  newInstance: false
})
```

Comment: Did you manage to solve this?

Comment: @akash How did you end up doing this?

Answer (score 0):

use **Firebase Dynamic Link**

[Receive Firebase Dynamic Links on Android](https://firebase.google.com/docs/dynamic-links/android/receive)

Create dynamic link with deep link from Firebase and just call the url of dynamic link.

You can adjust the behavior of the dynamic link from firebase console (for example: if the app is installed run this url using the app, if it is not installed use the browser)

Comment: This does not answer the question, which is about e2e testing deep linking with detox. I am using firebase dynamic links and everything works just fine, but would like to have an e2e test to spot possible regressions in the future.

Comment: it is an Android problem, not detox problem. you can can set your app as a default app for this link if you want to solve it manually.

Comment: That would also solve my problem! I have created an intent filter with the autoVerify property, but it doesn't seem to do anything ... Do you know if the autoVerify option also works for non-publicly available apps? (currently still in beta)

Comment: @dentemm check this answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36211104/intent-filter-with-androidautoverify-true-never-verified-at-installation-d

Comment: @dentemm How did you end up doing this?

Comment: Hello Jabbar, still isn't fully resolved. I believe the app link verification simply doesn't work for non-published apps ...

Answer (score 0):

place your package in sourceApp parameter

```
 await device.launchApp({
    newInstance: true,
    url: 'scheme://some.url',
    sourceApp: 'com.example.yourpackage'
  });
```

Comment: It seems sourceApp is only available on `openUrl`, and only on iOS (which is already working fine). It's Android which is holding me back